# Automatic network location in Lion

Tags: network, system-settings

I'm looking for a Lion compatible application similar to [AirportLocation](https://airportlocation.wordpress.com/) that will automatically change the Network Location based on my current location.

It's becoming a bigger and bigger pain to change it every day, manually. I have different settings for home and for work. I'll also be adding several new places in up coming weeks.

It's a shame that [AirportLocation](https://airportlocation.wordpress.com/) isn't compatible with Lion because it's exactly what I was after and more!

**Edit: I've seen an application called [Sidekick](http://oomphalot.com/sidekick/), but I'm preferably after a free application, bash script, whatever.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I forked MarcoPolo for the explicit purpose of getting it working right on Snow Leopard and Lion.  I use it on Lion everyday, everything should be working perfectly.

http://controlplane.dustinrue.com/

https://github.com/dustinrue/ControlPlane

Comment: Does ControlPane use Location Services? If it could detect that I'm within home area, and then change settings - that would be awesome!

Comment: That's in the works.  In fact, if you download the source from github right now it's all there and should be working ok.  That said, just using the WiFi evidence source will work perfect as location services basically does the same thing on OS X.

Comment: Then Dustin, ControlPlane is everything I need! Thank you for your time and support :D I'll be following ControlPane (and hopefully learning some objective-c to help support it!)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Lion machine available right now to test this, but I've been digging [ControlPlane 1.0.6](http://controlplane.dustinrue.com/) on Snow Leopard for a week now, works great on my work MBP.  Worth a look, LMK if it works on 10.7.